# Is there a way to assign conditions to sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a sql statement which will update product_quantity, if and only if the current value is less than the one to be updated...Would you pls give an example how to add conditions to the statement .

```
 UPDATE Product
 SET product_quantity='5'
 WHERE id='2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to the where conditions. `5` should be replaced by your dynamic value in both cases ofc.

```
UPDATE Product
SET product_quantity='5'
WHERE id='2' AND product_quantity < 5
```

You can also use

```
UPDATE Product
SET product_quantity= GREATEST('5', product_quantity)
WHERE id='2'
```

But i think the FIRST option is the better choice:

- The Update is conditional, meaning: Condition does not match: No Update.
- The Second Version will ALWAYS update the row, even if the value is equal.

This may have impact, if you are tracking the latest change time or sth. like that.

Comment: You cannot use `MAX` like this. You need to use `GREATEST()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE Product
SET product_quantity = 5
WHERE id = 2 AND product_quantity < 5
```

Or like what @dognose have said, you can use `GREATEST()` function.

```
UPDATE Product
SET product_quantity = GREATEST(5, product_quantity)
WHERE id = 2
```

Or you can use a simple condition like this

```
UPDATE Product
SET product_quantity = (
     CASE WHEN product_quantity < 5 THEN 5 
     ELSE product_quantity END
)
WHERE id = 2
```